# datatable with dynamically created table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

Inside an ajax success, I am appending trying to rows into an already existing datatable. The append became successful but it looses datatable features.

Please refer my code below.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function(evt){ 
       evt.preventDefault()
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "hello.aspx/ProcessMe",
           data: '{id: "' + $(this).prev().val() + '" ,dept:"' + $(this).prev().prev().val() + '"}',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {  //variable 'data' will get a string array from 'ProcessMe' C# function
             if (typeof data != "undefined" && data.d !== null) {
              $("#grdAll").empty(); //grdAll is the id of my aspx gridview which was already a datatable that is being generated before this ajax call for some other purpose.
              //all rows cleared.. now i will append new records.

           $('#grdAll').append("<tr><th>blah</th><th>blah</th>  ....... </tr>");
               for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
              $('#grdAll').append("<tr>" +
                 "<td>" + data.d[i + 1] + "</td>" + //getting array values
                  "<td>" + data.d[i + 2] + "</td>" +
                    ....................................//some script                           
"<td> <input type='hidden' name='blah' id='blah' value='" + data.d[i] + "'>" +
     "<a id='lnkProcess' class='btn btn-primary btn-round icnsml' data-original-title='' title='Process'>" +
  "<i class='fa fa-play-circle'></i>" +
 "</a>" 
 "</td>"
 );
 i++;
 }
    Now i am trying to make it as a datatable
   $('#grdAllTokens').DataTable({
............ //some code
  "retrieve": true
});
});
});
```

But i am not successful in getting is a datatable. I cant see sort options, styling etc.

But i can see the search box of datatble and footer messages are already there and search will produce correct result in footer message.

As an example if i search there for 'blahblahblah' it will display   "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from 1 total entries)"

Comment: @BrettCaswell I have edited my question. Sorry for my bad English. Hope it is clear now . I just want the newly generated table  should get datatable features like sort,search etc

Comment: The site has a lot of documentation and examples! https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: Yes. But i am trying to add it in this way. After receiving a variable of arrays